# How to push folder into user's phone along with app?

Tags: android, directory

When a user installs my app, I also want to push a folder into their phone. Is this possible?
For example, I have a folder with music samples and I want this folder to also be downloaded and saved in the user's phone. Please assist me for the same.

Comment: when the app is installed run the app and create a folder. Download the music samples to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download it the first time your app is run
2. Bundle it with the app itself in the `/assets` or `/res/raw` folder
3. Use [apk expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) to have it downloaded to the user's device along with the rest of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in assets and it would be installed in the application's data folder.
If you want it in the sdcard, you could run a download the first time the application runs.